# SQL for list of columns values that change against another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, count, distinct

I have a table of Events that contains Team ID's and Client ID's.  Although the two columns usually have the same corresponding values the TeamID might change from time to time against a particular ClientID.

I need to get a list of Client ID's whose Team ID's will have changed and the teamids they have changed to

I started off with

```
    SELECT ClientID AS CID 
    FROM 
    (SELECT TeamID, count(*) as Counter 
 FROM `vEvents` 
 GROUP BY `ClintID`) AS tbl WHERE Counter > 1
```

But I think I'm barking up the wrong tree.  Any help greatly appreciated

Andrew

Comment: Do you have time stamp for each record for tracking the change, like lastModifiedDate?

Comment: I have a dateCreated,dateModified and dateVerified column.  The verified seems to contain no null values.

Answer (score 0):

May this help you or give your hint

```
create table Clients (ID int identity(1,1),
                      TeamID int not null,
                      ClientID int not null,
                      LastModifiedDate datetime not null
                      )

insert Clients values
(1,1001,DATEADD(mi,-5,GETDATE())),
(2,1002,DATEADD(mi,-7,GETDATE())),
(3,1001,GETDATE())          

SELECT ClientID, TeamID
FROM Clients
WHERE ClientID in (select ClientID from Clients group by ClientID having COUNT(TeamID)>1)
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.  the Client ID needs to been shown twice if the corresponding Team ID value has changed.  So where the team id has not changed the client id is not in the result set.  The list I'm given with that query is a list of all clients and their ID

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question, I update the query, is this what you want?

Comment: I thank that might be close enough  - need to cross reference the data to make sure but wont be able to do that until tomorrow.  I added a disticnt to the first Select and order by ClientID so that I can see what clients have changed teams. Many thanks  andrew